# SPA security using Backbone.js, Require.js and Laravel

Tags: security, backbone.js, requirejs, laravel

I'm currently searching the best way for developing my next webapplication. I'm thinking about using Backbone.js and build a single page application. But I really can't imagine how to secure my app since nearly everything is done on client side. Of course I just could prevent the users from accessing my RESTful Api so they would not have access to my data. But all the view/model/collection/template js files are still accessible.

Or is there a known way to serve the js files with php (laravel), which would allow me to only serve the files I need for the respective user.

I just couldn't find a solution by searching the Web. But I just don't think that I am the lonely person who needs a clean and secure authentication method including different user rights.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered serve only a compiled version of your code, using r.js supplied together with require.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend application will fetch data from a backend (= API), and probably send back some changes.
This code can't have "security holes / leaks" as long as your backend is secured.
If you are afraid of people stealing your code, you can always minify the JS (check grunt.js and almond.js for this)

To secure your backend you can make use of Laravel's auth class, and the auth filter as mentioned before.

Besides normal auth, you could implement roles, that you can assign to specific users, giving them more or less access to certain resources in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I would try :

Separate the application in two parts.

One part - login via regular Laravel Auth on a separate page, and then when the user is logged in serve the single page app in a different view.

Wouldn't this work?

Comment: Of course it would, but you then only are able to secure the whole application and not several parts of it with different user rights. 
And you still won't be able to secure your js files.

Comment: What do you mean you won't be able to secure your js files? In Laravel you can put an Auth filter on anything, on any Route or Controller. you can definitely protect just the parts of the application that you want to be secured. Without logging in the user would have no idea where your js files are!

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are no different than any other web application you build.  At the end of the day you are exposing functionality to the client (which is also the attacker).  It doesn't matter what the client is implemented in,  if you expose dangerous functionality you will be hacked.

Have a session state,  keep track of the user id and make sure that the user is only accessing resources they have been allowed to access.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean with the "session state" and "ressources"? Backbone code or content data served by the server? I think its not possible to prohibit access to js files depending on a session state on the client side. Or am I completely wrong?

I'm just not sure if its a good thing that everyone can access my backbone.js code which in some way is a mirror of my database structure.

Comment: @Marcel  Server resources,  server session sate.   No further explication can be made.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that what JS/template files are exposed really matters. Essentially, you should only be allowing data interaction to authenticated users. Think of this as two separate applications.

1. The front-end application logs in, and a cookie is stored (or some other persistence is used).
2. The back-end application then uses the persistent authentication to validate every single user request for data, and every user action.

This way you don't have to worry about the security, the client can only fetch the data that the server allows it to, and, likewise, it can only interact with the data insofar as the server allows it. You shouldn't be relying on the client side for security anyway, even logged in, otherwise some malicious user could, conceivably, save all your frontend code and use it against you without authentication.

Comment: As stated in my post I know that although everyone has access to my Backbone files, no one could access my data on the server. 

You may be right with "I do not think that what JS/template files are exposed really matters" but I just don't really like it. Perhaps I'm just paranoid...

Comment: I understand why you don't want it seen, I had the same concern, but it would be the same if you were delivering a desktop app. All the code would be there for the user to play with, but the server it uses would be locked down and therefore there would be no danger in it (as long as you don't hardcore passwords, of course :P)